# How to omit .htacess rewrite rules to some particlar folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have written a .htaccess file for my drupal website to redirect any capitial letter on the url to small letter using the code below.

```
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [E=HASCAPS:TRUE,S=1]



  # Skip this entire section if no uppercase letters in requested URL
  RewriteRule ![A-Z] - [S=28]

  # Replace single occurance of CAP with cap, then process next Rule.
  RewriteRule ^([^A]*)A(.*)$ $1a$2
  RewriteRule ^([^B]*)B(.*)$ $1b$2
  RewriteRule ^([^C]*)C(.*)$ $1c$2
  RewriteRule ^([^D]*)D(.*)$ $1d$2
  RewriteRule ^([^E]*)E(.*)$ $1e$2
  RewriteRule ^([^F]*)F(.*)$ $1f$2
  RewriteRule ^([^G]*)G(.*)$ $1g$2
  RewriteRule ^([^H]*)H(.*)$ $1h$2
  RewriteRule ^([^I]*)I(.*)$ $1i$2
  RewriteRule ^([^J]*)J(.*)$ $1j$2
  RewriteRule ^([^K]*)K(.*)$ $1k$2
  RewriteRule ^([^L]*)L(.*)$ $1l$2
  RewriteRule ^([^M]*)M(.*)$ $1m$2
  RewriteRule ^([^N]*)N(.*)$ $1n$2
  RewriteRule ^([^O]*)O(.*)$ $1o$2
  RewriteRule ^([^P]*)P(.*)$ $1p$2
  RewriteRule ^([^Q]*)Q(.*)$ $1q$2
  RewriteRule ^([^R]*)R(.*)$ $1r$2
  RewriteRule ^([^S]*)S(.*)$ $1s$2
  RewriteRule ^([^T]*)T(.*)$ $1t$2
  RewriteRule ^([^U]*)U(.*)$ $1u$2
  RewriteRule ^([^V]*)V(.*)$ $1v$2
  RewriteRule ^([^W]*)W(.*)$ $1w$2
  RewriteRule ^([^X]*)X(.*)$ $1x$2
  RewriteRule ^([^Y]*)Y(.*)$ $1y$2
  RewriteRule ^([^Z]*)Z(.*)$ $1z$2

  # If there are any uppercase letters, restart at very first RewriteRule in file.
  RewriteRule [A-Z] - [N]

  RewriteCond %{ENV:HASCAPS} TRUE
```

I just write this code to rewrite the url on the browser. But after adding this code when i access any images using image which is having any capital letter in image src the capitial letter change to small letter.

for example when in access `<img src="A.jpeg" />` it become `<img src='a.jpeg' />`. But the image stored on the server with A.jpeg, so i cannot access this image. How can i resolve this issue without renaming the image but still i need all my browser link in small letter event if user enter capital letter.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a condition which ignores some file types, this might be easier in your case:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$
```

You can also add more filetypes by adding them in the `()` seperated by a pipe `|`

**Edit:**

Additionally you can catch all file types using the `-f` keyword:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

or an entire directory (folder) using `-d`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Comment: Actually where to put this block of code. I had placed it in top but it is not working.

Comment: Try it directly after `RewriteEngine On`